# FOSUserBundle not working in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a website that has a lot of traffic and the nature of the website means that it can have a lot of requests in a specific time period.

I use amazon beanstalk to manage the load balancer and instances.

I can have up to 20 instances running and because FOSUserBundle uses Sessions to hold the data  I am loosing users logins etc.

I know EB has stickiness but due to the nature of the site it gets overwhelmed and sometimes doesnt forward the correct user to the correct instance so I am loosing users again. Amazon are no help at all.

Is there a way to override this to use secure cookies (i know cookies arent secure but I could create my own crypt/decrypt method)

Any suggestions would be helpful :)

Comment: [NEVER create your own encryption system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651090/home-made-cryptography).

Comment: i wasn't going to go off and write one in c or what not but i mean my own function to encrypt and decrypt a bit more securely than crypt etc

Comment: Did you solve this?  Our non-symfony application is working fine with AWS ELB, and Elasticache / memcache sessions configured in php.ini.  The Symfony2 +  FOSRestbundle login is not.  We disabled CSRF, and still no luck.  When we only have 1 server in in our ELB it works, but once we add a second it stops.  It also works with sticky sessions and multiple servers in the ELB.  This leads us to believe it something in symfony2, and maybe there are different headers being set when the ELB only has 1 server, or when sticky is turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found away to essentially negate the sessions stored on one server. I remember doing this with a custom php system (using this [php net session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) I built a few years ago but did not think it would work with symfony. Since posting this questions I found PdoSessionStorage basically storing your sessions on a Database instead of files on the server or instances.

Please choose your syfmony version as namespaces sometimes change version to version

[Link to PdoSessionStorage on Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html)